# user32.dll proxy redirect for local program OR user32.dll linking issue

Tags: c++, windows, dll, redirect, proxy

I have created a proxy for user32.dll that replaces lpCaption with the text "MessageBoxA" and "MessageBoxW" for the functions MessageBoxA and MessageBoxW, as you may have already guessed.
I used wrappit.cpp from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/CreateYourProxyDLLs.aspx) to generate the initial code, and after making the modifications, compiled it with:

`cl user32.cpp /link /dll /def:user32.def /out:user32.dll`
It compiled fine, however the small MessageBox test program I wrote is not displaying the modified caption, as it would if the program was using the dll redirect. The test program displays a MessageBox via the MessageBoxA function. I've tried compiling the test program with:
`cl testWin.cpp` and: `cl /MD testWin.cpp`
My guess is that I might not be linking to user32.dll, and if so then my question is "is there a problem with the way I am linking the test program?"
If I am linking correctly, which I am not sure that I am, then my question is "why isn't the dll redirect happening?"
A msdn article on DLL/COM Redirection on Windows that I read suggests creating an empty file named "testWin.exe.local" in the same directory, but this does not seem to effect the outcome.

If I can provide any additional information that may help you help me, let me know.

I have uploaded my project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?0b510et7ddad5db).

The archive only contains source files, no binaries.

Comment: Try to create your dll first under a different name, for example `user32a`. Then try to MessageBox from the test code. I tried this, and it did not work, the test program started and stopped, without showing a message box.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and testWin used user32a.dll, and replaced lpCaption as I was wanting it to. So, apparently the dll redirect works if it's not named user32.dll. Is there a way to get this working as an actual dll redirect that overrides c:\Windows\System32\user32.dll?

Comment: I answered my own question. The *.local method was unreliable, but there is another more annoying method, *.manifest. Luckily a manifest file can be embedded into a dll. I read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) if anyone is interested.

Comment: Could you explain what needs to be done with the manifest? I have the same issue - my DLL has a "default" Vs2010 generated manifest.